# How to read one row from mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, row

I have profiles of users in mysql and I want to read one row (of some user) and add values to object "user"

Here is part of my code: ( function that return user)

```
connection.Open();

person person_1 = new person();

//1. Read name
string sql = "select name from profili where name=@name and surname=@surname";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, konekcija);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", name);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", surname);

MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read()) {

  person_1.name = reader["name"].ToString();


//2. Read surname
string sql = "select surname from profili where name=@name and surname=@surname";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, konekcija);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", name);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", surname);
    person_1.surname = reader["surname"].ToString();
return person_1;
```

With this I only get name, surname is null ( see that in debbuger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. You already know the surname and the name because you pass them as parameters for the WHERE condition. A part from this, the problem with surname being null is the fact that you don't execute the second command.

You should add

```
//2. Read surname
string sql = "select surname from profili where name=@name and surname=@surname";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, konekcija);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlType.VarChar).Value = name;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", MySqlType.VarChar).Value = surname;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
person_1.surname = reader["surname"].ToString();
```

Said that, it makes no sense to execute a command two times to retrieve a single row. Your query text could easily add all the column names that you want to retrieve and execute just one read

```
//1. Read the row matching the known surname and name 
string sql = @"select name, surname, column1, column2, colx 
              from profili where name=@name and surname=@surname";

cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, konekcija);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlType.VarChar).Value = name;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", MySqlType.VarChar).Value = surname;
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read()) {
   person_1.name = reader["name"].ToString();
   person_1.surname = reader["surname"].ToString();
   person_1.Property1 = reader["column1"].ToString();
   ...and so on for other columns
```

Comment: Add is deprecated, use AddWithValue

Comment: Well neither AddWithValue is recommended. See [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). However is true that this form of Add is deprecated. The OP should use the overload of Add that uses three parameters, the name, the type and value or just combine in a single line as I have changed the answer above